# Use of indefinite article with relative clause

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, articles, usage

I posted a question quite long time ago asking whether "**that was a day that my dog died**" is valid. The answers said "no!", telling that a dog cannot die twice.

I thought it was possible, for I thought I was introducing an item for the fist time, for which the indefinite article is necessary.

So I searched around and found this sentence: "**this is a book I told you about yesterday.**"

The answerer was saying that "it might suggest that it was one of several books, or **it might mean that you don't think I remember it**", which is similar to introducing an item for the first time, because the listener does not have any information about it due to inability to remember it.

But some others said that "**this is a book I told you about yesterday** can only be sensibly used when the book is one of several that I told you about. Whether I think you remember or not is irrelevant."

So I came to this conclusion:

***When a noun modified by a relative clause is used, the indefinite article is used only for the situations in which the noun is one of several.***

I was naively happy with the satisfaction that I cleared up some confusion. Yet it occurred again, when I found that:

> A woman who fell 10 meters from High Peak was lifted to safety by a
>   helicopter.

is actually valid, even though there was only one woman who fell 10 meter from High Peak (it would be strange if there were more than one).

And more surprising was that the reason for its validity was because it was introduced for the first time, news they said. "This is news. We haven't heard about this woman before."

Here is the question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265002/using-the-in-adjective-relative-clause

So I just cannot see the difference between "**this is a book I told you about yesterday**" and  "**a woman who fell 10 meters from High Peak was lifted to safety by a helicopter.**"

Why can a definite article be used with "woman" for introducing for the first time and not with "book"?

Also, these two uses puzzled me even further.

> “Everywhere there is growing interest in the Exposition,” he told
>   Burnham in **a** June 20 letter from Biltmore.

It should be "the" according to the explanation people have given me, right? Unless there is more than one letter he sent to Burnham on June 20, which is unlikely.

> While aboard the train, Burnham wrote **a** letter to Olmsted that
>   contained a less-than-candid description of the meeting with the
>   architects.

Likewise, it should be "the" unless Burnham wrote several letters that contained a description of the meeting.

I fail to notice how this "letter" is different from "day". There was only one letter as there was only one day that my dog died. So why indefinite article cannot be used with "day" as used above?

It became a rather long question.

However, my central question is, what controls the use of the definite and indefinite article when modifying a noun with relative clause?

Comment: If you told someone yesterday about the book in question, that person already knows time what book you are talking about and thus the definite article "the" is correct. If you talked about several books, you'd normally say "This is one of the books I told you about yesterday".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it all comes down to what the writer/speaker thinks about the reader/listener

ie. If it is new to the reader use 'a', otherwise use 'the'

---

## as for your examples

> > So I just cannot see the difference between "this is a book I told you about yesterday" and "a woman who fell 10 meters from High Peak was lifted to safety by a helicopter."
>
> Why can a definite article be used with "woman" for introducing for the first time and not with "book"?

If you told me about the book yesterday, then it wouldnt be new information so it would be: "this is **the** book i told you about yesterday", Using 'a' in this case almost implies that I forgot about it, and you are reminding me

For the second one, I have never heard of the[1] woman (in the article) before so you describe her as 'a' woman and not 'the' woman.

---

the[1] last examples:

> It should be "the" according to the explanation people have given me, right? Unless there is more than one letter he sent to Burnham on June 20, which is unlikely.

This does read to me as if there is more than one or that he wrote so many letters over the years that they can only specify which one they are talking about by date.

> Likewise, it should be "the" unless Burnham wrote several letters that contained a description of the meeting.

it is 'a' because he wrote only one letter. "Burnham wrote **one** letter to Olmsted...", if you said 'the' in this case, it would imply that I knew about the letter before you said the sentence

[1] I use 'the' because you know what I'm refering to here

Comment: The second one is  "a letter that contained a less-than-candid description of the meeting with the architects", which makes it so specific. Likewise, it should be "the" unless Burnham wrote several letters that contained a description of the meeting, I think.

Comment: if it was so specific as to identify it (from other letters), then the writer couldve used 'the', in this case it all depends on what the writer wants to say and what they assume of the reader.

Comment: Thanks!  What do you think of "the day my dog died" and ""a day my dog died"?

Comment: "the" seems more natural, since 'a' would imply it happened more than once (ie. "one day my dog died). "Oh july 13th, thats the day my dog died", in context we are already refering to the day so its no longer new information

Comment: I don't get the difference between "a letter that contained a less-than-candid description of the meeting with the architects" and "the day my dog died". Both of them have very specific detail, and both of them are...just one! Just one specific letter, and just one day. So why one uses "a" and the other "the"?

Comment: Context is really important for article use. For the letter, the previous sentences (I'm assuming) and the start of that sentence don't refer to the letter so it is new information.**** For the dog, the start of the sentence or the previous sentences would have to refer to the day I'm talking about or else it would make no sense. (No-one would say "a day my dog died" without any context, and with context you would use "the")

Comment: Could you please give an example of context with "the day my dog died"? I don't quite get it.

Comment: "Yesterday was the day my dog died", ("yesterday" is the day im talking about).  "The day my dog died was two weeks before Christmas" ("December 11th" is the day im referring to). It is not likely that someone would talk about 'a day my dog died' since without specifying what day that happened the listener would be confused

Comment: I truly appreciate your effort. There is one more thing that makes me very curious though. Would saying "this is **a** book I discussed with my friend" to a third person, with that book the only book I was discussing with my friend, would it be natural to say that?

Comment: Yes it would be natural, 'a' would be fine in both cases (one or many books). However, if you spoke to this third person before (ie in the past) about discussing with your friend then "the" would be correct as well. -----Examples----- "Oh Jake!, this is *the* article I talked with john about" (this means I already told Jake I spoke to John about an article) ***** "Oh Jake! this is an article I spoke to John about" (This means I probably didnt tell jake before about this and only just was reminded about it)

Comment: Thank you, thank you! Now I can almost conclude that use of articles is governed by whether the listener knows what I'm talking about or not. But you see, I found this online "**He bought _the_ house with a big backyard.** _This combination tells the listener which specific house he bought._" and "**He bought _a_ house with a big backyard.** _This combination tells the listener what kind of house he bought, but not the specific house he bought._" So I guess "the" won't work if the listener does not have any information about the house before hearing about it, right? Or is it possible to say...

Comment: ...it to a listener who never heard about this house with "the" for the purpose of specification?

Comment: The italicized parts seem correct based on my experience as a native speaker. However I would personally say "He bought the house with **the** big backyard" if I was trying to specify which house (out of a group) he chose to purchase. (as opposed to "the house without a big backyard") ---- But to answer your question, ""the" won't work if the listener does not have any information about the house before hearing about it".

Comment: ie. as the listener I have no idea what house you are referring to. But if I was his real estate agent or something and you told me, "Oh he bought the house with the big backyard", since I know the options he had, I would know what they are referring to.

Comment: So... my guess that "the" won't work if the listener does not have any information about the house before hearing about it is correct? I don't know if you were restating my question or if you were answering my question...sorry.

Comment: You are correct. "the" requires background info for the listener to understand.

Answer (score 4):

I think the some of the answer revolves around the assumption of prior knowledge we make of the listener. We choose a form of words that is politely appropriate for the listener's assumed knowledge - note that this does not actually necessitate that this really is what the listener knows.

Situation: I spoke to the listener yesterday, we spoke about one book, he recommended the book to me, I'm pretty sure that he will remember the conversation.

> This is the book we spoke about yesterday.

Situation: I spoke to the listener yesterday, we spoke about many books, although he may remember the entire conversation he cannot know which particular book I'm holding:

> This is a book we spoke about yesterday

Situation: A woman has fallen. This is a news program, we have no reason to suppose that our listeners know this particular woman. We cannot say

> The woman has fallen

the listener has no point of reference, in fact the woman's effective identity is that she fell and was rescued

> a woman who fell ...

The letters work in the same way. We the listener have never seen the letters, have no point of reference, if we said "the letter" they would feel that we are assuming knowledge they have yet to receive. So we say "a letter" and then clarify by reference to the content

> XXX wrote a letter, which ...

Note. If we were in a museum and could see the letter our guide might say:

> Look at this letter written by X on Date.

we now have our point of reference, so he can now say

> The letter ...

Your original example is slightly more subtle

> This was the day my dog died

We use **the** because we are immediately going to give a very specific point of reference.

We could do something similar for dramatic effect with the letter

> While aboard the train, Burham wrote the fateful letter.

In effect we are playing a game with the listener, he knows that we haven't given him the full point of reference, but we have given him information that some very specific detail will be coming shortly.

> this was the day (... dramatic tension ...) my dog died

Comment: Thank you. So never, never "this is a book we talked about" if the listener and I talked about only one book?

Comment: I would not say "never": the big question is it polite to imply that he should have the point of reference where "the" is understood. In normal conversation I would probably give my listener the point of reference. "Ah Doctor Smith, so nice to have that conversation about xxx yesterday. Here's the book that I mentioned."  "Ah Doctor Smith, it is good to see you again. I came across a book we discussed last year."

Comment: Also I don't get the difference between "**a** letter that contained a less-than-candid description of the meeting with the architects" and "**the** day my dog died". Both of them do not have specific point of reference, and both of them have very specific detail. So why one uses "a" and the other "the"?

Comment: @whitedevil You can have "a day my dog died" in a fantasy setting for example where your dog dies multiple times. The essential reason IMO for the necessity of "the day my dog died" is that death the way we understand it is unique. You can't die multiple times so it must be "the" specific day. Somewhat surprisingly it would still generally be "the day one of my dogs died" eventhough now you get multiple.

Comment: OK.... but then how is "**a** letter that contained a less-than-candid description of the meeting with the architects" possible? My understanding is that there is only one letter, as there is only one day that my dog died. So why can you use "a" with this specific letter? Or is it that how specific information nouns contain do not matter, and usually only whether one knows it or not matter, but death is a special case that goes against it?

Answer (score 0):

In the examples of the letters, in each case the description of the letter (written on that date, containing that account) is, at least in grammar, subordinate to the mention of the letter's existence, which is new and thus has ‘a’ rather than ‘the’.  You could split the sentence in two:

> Burnham wrote a letter to Olmsted.  The letter contained ...

But you would not say

> That was a day.  My dog died on the day.

... partly because the existence of the day is not news to the listener.